# Parameters leading to an elementary integral

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

> For which values of $a,b$ the following integral is an elementary
>   function, and which elementary function?
>
> $$\int \frac{x^2+ax+b}{(x-1)^2}\,e^x\, dx$$

I tried to solve this integral but it is too hard, someone can help me please, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative? (I am not, I've just seen it on wolframalpha).

Comment: Yes but when I tried to solve $(x^2+ax+b)/(x-1) =1$ i get a solution so large

Comment: @Knight: but the solutions of $f(x)=1$ have nothing to do with the integrability of $f$ in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x}{(x-1)} = \frac{(x-2)}{(x-1)^2}e^{x} $$
hence if
$$ \frac{x^2+ax+b}{(x-1)^2} = 1+k\frac{x-2}{(x-1)^2} $$
i.e. $\color{red}{2a+b = -3}$, we have an elementary integral, $\color{red}{\left(1+\frac{a+2}{x-1}\right)e^x}$.

Some [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) is required to prove that the previous *if* is in fact an *iff*.

Answer (score 1):

it is very unlikely that any function multiplied by $e^x$ has an elemental derivative, so the goal is to make $\frac{x^2+ax+b}{(x-1)^2}$ into a constant.

expand the bottom of the fraction.
$$\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2-2x+1}$$

As you can see, the top and bottom line up perfectly. if $a=-2$ and $b=1$, the numerator and denominator become the same, so your function simplifies into $\int{e^x}dx$, and is elemental.

I don't know if there are more correct answers, but it is safe to assume that there are not any, because any other values for $a$ and $b$ would result in the integral becoming more complicated than is expected of you in precalc.

tl/dr: a=-2, b=1.

Comment: You know that $\int e^x (f(x)+f'(x))dx $ is also elementary?

Comment: @Nikunj no I didn't. That works for any f(x)? I'll have to explore this...

Comment: Yup, try by parts on $e^xf(x)$